Proving inequality involving mean, covariance and their estimate.
Let $$ A =  \left( I - \frac{\Sigma \iota \iota'}{\iota' \Sigma \iota} \right) (\mu - \hat \mu) +    \gamma  \left( I - \frac{\Sigma \iota \iota'}{\iota' \Sigma \iota} \right)(\hat \Sigma \iota), \gamma > 0.$$
Let $$B =  \gamma  \left( I - \frac{\Sigma \iota \iota'}{\iota' \Sigma \iota} \right)(\hat \Sigma \iota)$$
Where $\Sigma$ is the true $nxn$ covariance matrix of a random vector x that is normally distributed with mean $\mu$, $\hat \Sigma$ is an estimate for this covariance matrix, $\hat \mu$ is an estimate for the mean and $\iota$ is a vector of ones of size nx1.
The estimate can be the sample covariance or a Bayesian estimate using the sample covariance and a prior, or in general, a positive definite matrix. Likewise, for the mean it can be any vector.
I want to understand under what conditions
$$E[A'A] > E[B'B]$$ or $$E[A'\Sigma^{-1}A] > E[B'\Sigma^{-1}B].$$
Ideally, in the case where $\hat \Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix or $\hat \Sigma = \Sigma + D$ where D is a positive definite matrix and when $\hat \mu$ is a vector.
So far, I can only show that if $\hat \Sigma = b \Sigma, b != 0$, then $B = 0$.
We can assume for now $E[B'\Sigma^{-1}B] > 0$ if $\hat \Sigma != b \Sigma$.
Expanding the product does not seem to help in any obvious way.
I would also appreciate guidance but would prefer an answer.
